# How to ignore jquery variable?

Tags: jquery

I have code, that looks something like this:

```
  (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

    function getHash(){
        var h = document.location.href.split('#');
        return h.length == 1 ? "" : h[1];
    }


    var $newdiv = $('...html code here...');

function checkit() {
    if(getHash() != "#ignoreDivButton")
        $('html').html($newdiv);    
}

checkit();


    $('#ignoreDivButton').click(function(){
   document.location.href = document.location.href.split('#')[0] + "#ignoreDivButton";
    location.reload();
    });

    });
    })(jQuery);
```

What I need, is to reload page by clicking on  #ignoreDivButton but without loading the newdiv. I just can't get how to ignore the variable. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can set a variable into a cookie, localStorage or even into the url(hash) :

```
function getHash(){
    var h = document.location.href.split('#');
    return h.length == 1 ? "" : h[1];
}

$(window).load(function() {
    if(getHash() != "ignoreDivButton")
        $('html').html($newdiv);    
});

$('#ignoreDivButton').click(function(){
    //reload the page and set the hash of the url to ignoreDivButton
    document.location.href = document.location.href.split('#')[0] + "#ignoreDivButton";
})
```

Comment: Yup this option seems to be perfect to me, thank you!. However, I've faced several problems. Firstly, with `(window).load` it's seems that links aren't working, so I've changed it a bit (look the update). Now I'm getting the `index.html#ignoreDivButton` but it doesn't actually doing the IF part. Can you suggest what should I do in this situation?

Comment: @Maay the `getHash` function returns the string withouth the "#" char, so you  should change the `if(getHash() != "#ignoreDivButton")` to `if(getHash() != "ignoreDivButton")`

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of just reloading the location, you append some sort of tag to the URL, like `#second_load` and then test for the token in the URL before setting your `$newdiv` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it will always load newdiv right now, simply because you never limited it, try having a variable in a cookie that states whether the div should be loaded or not (you can simply use javascript for this.. check out a website like w3schools if you don't know how to use them).

Then simply add an if statement before the $('html').html($newdiv);